# Updating all row id after deletion of a row

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to update all the row id after a row is deleted. For example: in a collection of records with row id 1,2,3,4,5; if 2 is deleted it should be 1,2,3,4. This is my code:

```
getID = Int32.Parse(forms.Get("IDNo"));
var ID = from x in db.tblServiceRegister_D
         where x.Company_Code == COMP && x.SR_No == SR_No
         select x.ID;
var maxID = ID.Max();

short loop = Convert.ToInt16(maxID - getID);
tblServiceRegister_D tblserviceregisterD = db.tblServiceRegister_D.Find(COMP,SR_No,getID);

db.tblServiceRegister_D.Remove(tblserviceregisterD);
            try
            {               
                db.SaveChanges();
                strResponse = "Record deleted";

                for (int i = 1; i <= loop; i++)
                {
                    short x = Convert.ToInt16(getID);
                    tblServiceRegister_D newIDForSRD = db.tblServiceRegister_D.Find(COMP, SR_No, x+1);

                    newIDForSRD.ID = x;
                 ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(newIDForSRD, EntityState.Modified);
                 db.SaveChanges();
                    x++;

                }

            }
```

It only works until the deletion of the record. The IDs are not simply updating. Need help please.

Comment: Why would you want to do this ?!? The ID of a record is the unique identifier of that and only that record - other tables may depend on this being the case. What used to point to item 4 is now looking at the data for what was formerly item 5. If you are using identity columns which I think is what entity framework does, you can't change this anyway - hence your issue. But ... don't do it!

Comment: This table is not related to others. The ID i am showing just for indexing.The primary key is a composite primary key with ID. Anyway , it's necessary for me to do this :/

Comment: Even so, why change it - it will not make any difference to the speed of an index.

Comment: It is for showing an index to viewer; not for database indexing.

Comment: If you want to show an index to viewer, do select row number rather than update your id, because it can hurt your performance, and concurrency problem

Answer (score 0):

You could apply some logic to check whether the record that was deleted was at the end of the viewer's index so that you're not updating records when you don't need to, omit any index numbers less than the index that was just deleted, etc., but if you have any possibility of multiple deletions at once or other cases that would make it difficult or impossible to only target the nth record or higher it may be safer to use a "shotgun approach" and execute the statement below and use `context.ExecuteStoreCommand()` to call a stored procedure that performs your update rather than iterating over the contents of the table in your code and calling Save for each individual record.  As your table gets larger, of course, performance could become an issue.  For now, assuming that you want the user-viewable index to follow an order based on the table's primary key your SQL might look like:

```
UPDATE myTable SET RowIndex = tbl.RowNum  
FROM myTable  
JOIN 
(SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) RowNum
FROM myTable) tmp 
ON 
myTable.ID = tmp.ID
```